# Arrays with several sentences in C

Tags: c, arrays, swift, swift2

How can I do that? In Swift 2 I'd do something like that:

```
let test = [
    "I'm a sentence.",
    "Me too.",
    "What am I?",
    "I'm whatever"
]

print(test[1])
```

How do I do the same in C?

I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 const char strings[] = {
        "I'm a sentence.",
        "Me too.",
        "What am I?",
        "I'm whatever"
  };
  printf("%s", strings[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char strings[]` makes it possible to store one sentence in the array. `*` makes it possible to store unlimited amounts of strings in the array because it is an array of char*.

Comment: @Olaf Even if he don't understand what `*` is for, he will read about it now. He may have read books and made some programs, but sometimes what he studies fails him and need a little push forward to put him in the right course.

Comment: @Nasr Thanks! I'm learning C for about two weeks now, so of course not everything I do succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright...So first of all, understand what is going on here:

`"me too"` is an array of chars by itself, and so each of the sentences you put.
Also, a `char*` *points* to the first char in the sentence.

**Your Problem:**
you did not create an array that holds on all the sentences(aka points at each first char of each sentence), instead you defined `char strings[]` which is an array of chars, AKA points to only one sentence(`char*`, remember?)

However, instead you should declare an **array of char***, so you'll have this:

```
                 'o' <- 0X6
                 'o' <- 0X5
                 't' <- 0X4
                 ' ' <- 0X3
                 'e' <- 0X2
                 'm' <- 0X1
                  ^
                  |  . . .
                ----------------
char* arr[]:    | 0x1 |   |   |
                ----------------
```

Comment: I still don't get it. If I declare `char strings[]` I have an array where I can store `Me too` with `char strings[] = {"Me too"};`. If I want to store a second sentence in it, why do I need a pointer and not just something like `char strings[][] = .....`?

Comment: for each new sentence you need a char*, thus, you want an array of char*.
a rule of thumb: each `[]` means a pointer => `char[][] arr = char* arr[] = char** arr`

Comment: So: `char* strings[]` should be the same as `char strings[][]`? Because the second version doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

**example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  const char *strings[] = {
        "I'm a sentence.",
        "Me too.",
        "What am I?",
        "I'm whatever"
  };
  printf("strings[1]: %s\n", strings[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
$ ./test 
strings[1]: Me too.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I was completely correct with my solution except that I missed the `*` before `strings`. Why do I have to put the `*` there?

Comment: because the size of the member strings is not uniform. therefore we're initialising an array ( with known length ) of pointers ( size known ) pointing to string literal memory

Comment: @S.Eberl Without `*`, `strings` is an array of `char` which means that it can hold *one* string. With the `*`, `strings` is an array of `char*` which means that it can store *unlimited* amounts of strings (string literals, `char*`s)